# Wiremock to remove additional data (meta-data) in response

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am trying to post a file in wiremock and configure the file in mapping like below. And in the response I am seeing Content-Type, Content-Disposition etc, is there a way to disable this?

**POST file**

**http://localhost:8080/__admin/files/some.json**

###### used form-data to upload the file

contents of some.json

```
{
  "user": "xxx"
}
```

**To create mapping**

http://localhost:8080/__admin/mappings

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/some"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "some.json",
                "headers": {
          "Content-Type": [
            "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

**To check the api**

http://localhost:8080/some

Response:

```
----------------------------228585284577179878202292
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="some.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "user": "xxx"
}
----------------------------228585284577179878202292--
```

Like you see, there are additional content like below to the actual response. Wanted to disable the below. How to do this?

```
----------------------------228585284577179878202292
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="some.json"
    Content-Type: application/json
    
----------------------------228585284577179878202292--
```

Comment: Have you considered stubbing metadata ? http://wiremock.org/docs/stub-metadata/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of form-data choose binary while uploading the file. Then it return only the actual response...

```
{
  "user": "xxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a file by HTTP request to wiremock instance, as @Minisha said, add 'Content-type': 'binary' header to your put request. Here is an example with python [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/requests/sessions/#Session.put):

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'binary'}
requests.put(url=mock_wire_files_url_file_name, data=open(your_file, 'rb'), headers=headers)
```